# correct white balance in images using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I've got a folder with more than 2000 portrait photos. All of these are shot in front of a plain white canvas. The problem ist, that some of the pictures need a color correction - or to be more specific I have to set a white point.

I've found this script wich does exactly what I need to do:
http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/whitebalance/index.php

(Specify a white point and correct the balance)

My problem now is, that I have to run this on a windows server. There is no Linux environment and I cannot install any additional software.

Does anyone know a different way to accomplish this task using imagemagick on windows?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example on how to run it on DOS for a whole directory
The command is used for resize, but you will get the point.

```
for %j in (*.JPG) do convert %~nj.JPG -resize 2592x1728 %~nj_r.jpg
```